# Add a new line at the end of file

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed

I've seen ways of adding new line to each file (10 text files+ at once), but this normally involves creating a new file.. Is there a way to add a new line without the need for making a temp file (basically the source file and dest file should be the same).

Comment: Where have you seen these ways? Any method that involves creating a new file was written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing and you should find another source of information.

Comment: Do you want to add a *new line* or a *newline*?

Comment: Example: sed -e '$a\' test.txt > test-with-eol.txt (trying to avoid)

Comment: a new blank line? so if I cat many files I dont get merged lines

Comment: Try: `ex -s +"bufdo wq" *.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a newline character to the end of all text files in your working dir:

```
sed -i -e '$G' *.txt
```

Comment: This creates a new file, which the questioner specifically wished to avoid.  Since the answer was accepted, presumably the questioner does not understand the question (or does not understand the answer).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Good point, but it doesn't create any new files overall. The net result is still the same. I took the question as "how to avoid manually creating a temp file" and "what's the quickest way to add a newline to `EOF`". Also, I am not suggesting that my answer is any quicker (if any) than a bash append.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to **append** a line to a set of files, it is pretty easy even in a shell:

```
for file in $files ; do
    echo "$line" >> "$file"
done
```

If you want to add a line **in the middle** of the files, you have to use a temp file.

Comment: or slurp the file into an array, calculate the mid location, add it there, and overwrite the original file with that array.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you wanted to recurse through the current directory and add a line to the end of every *.txt file you found, you could do this:

```
find . *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "some text here" >> {}' \;
```